# Can I use the SqlServer NTEXT data type in LightSwitch?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-lightswitch

Can I use the SqlServer NTEXT data type in LightSwitch?

I know how to add extension business types, but they always subclass the existing LightSwitch base types. The LightSwitch base type 'String' maps to the SqlServer data type NVARCHAR which has a limit of 4000 characters (if I'm not mistaken).

I need more than 4000 characters!

Comment: But you can't do that in LightSwitch itself...

Comment: I don't know Lightswitch, but if you're mapping a string of potentially long length, your backend column should be nvarchar(max) which does not have the 4000 char limitation.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy, that would work for a 'normal' table, but this table is controlled by LightSwitch, so the NVARCHAR(MAX) would be overwritten next time I publish my project.

Comment: You do understnad that ntext is deprecated and should NOT be used in any new code.

Comment: Did not know that, HLGEM. What should I be using instead?

Comment: Once again, you should be using `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. This article seems to have a workaround for the limitation in LightSwitch: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/48/Using-the-Telerik-Rich-Text-Editor-In-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul -- Nvarchar(4000) is what lightswitch defaults, but you can change the properties of the field by clearing the maximum length field, which will change it to nvarchar(max).  Nvarchar(max) can store about 2Gb (much, much more than 4000 characters!)

Comment: Thank you kuru, I did not know that. And Microsoft does not state this clearly. Now I have got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Since `NTEXT` is deprecated, in order to use the proper data type (`NVARCHAR(MAX)`) in LightSwitch, create the table in SQL Server and then attach to it as an external table from LightSwitch. [Reference](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/48/Using-the-Telerik-Rich-Text-Editor-In-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch.aspx).